# How can i connect to robomongo in my windows to mongodb installed on amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, robo3t

I have installed mongodb v4.4.2 in my amazon linux 2 (on aws ec2 instance) and installed robomongo in my local windows machine. Now i want to connect to my db on ec2 but i always get this error window from robomongo:

> Cannot connect to the MongoDB at <ec2_ipv4>:27017.
>
> Error: Network is unreachable. Reason: couldn't connect to server
> <ec2_ipv4>:27017, connection attempt failed: NetworkTimeout: Error
> connecting to <ec2_ipv4>:27017 :: caused by :: Socket operation timed
> out

These are the things that i have done:

1. Changed bindIp field in /etc/mongod.conf(in ec2 linux) file to 0.0.0.0 and port already set to 27017
2. stopped and started the mongod server again.
3. Exposed the port 27017 in security groups in my aws account with tcp protocol with source set to 0.0.0.0/0
4. in robomongo created a new connection with address: "ipv4 address of ec2 instance" and port = 27017

Is there anything that i have missed. Why is my connection not being established?

Comment: Make sure you are using the public IP of the EC2 instance, not the private IP.

Comment: I just checked it , the label from where i got this ip says "IPv4 Public IP", so there must be some other issue.

Comment: Did you try to login into the EC2 MongoDB with the mongo shell?

Comment: i did not login into mongodb in ec2 , while doing the setup they didn't ask me for any mongodb credentials at any time,  i just downloaded it and started using it with mongo command, works totally fine

Comment: From what I've read from your question, you should be able to login into it, you allowed the port on the inbound rules right?

Comment: yes , i allowed the port on the inbound rules.

Comment: but still it is not working, what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by add EC2's private IPv4 as a bind IP in `/etc/mongod.conf`

so it would look like this

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,<your-ec2-private-ipv4>
```